# crystal report geeting blank while using stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure "ParkingSummary" that has three parameters. I try to pass a parameter to the crystal report but it doesn't show anything, it's getting blank.

Below is my code:

```
Dim strConn As String = con.ConnectionString
Dim rpt As New Test
Dim sqla = New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds = New DataSet

sqla.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("ParkingSummary @locid, @startdate, @enddate", con.connect)
sqla.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locid", 5)
sqla.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", "2013/1/1")
sqla.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", "2013/1/1")
sqla.Fill(ds, strConn)
rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

what is wrong in this code?, please help me to find out.

Comment: Please start by reading the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [edit]ing your question so that it is readable. Also, in English, sentences end with a period (`.`), not a series of commas. Help us help you.

Comment: sir,,i edited the code, could you please help me to figour out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
sqla.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("ParkingSummary @locid, @startdate, @enddate", con.connect)
```

to

```
sqla.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("ParkingSummary", con.connect)
```

and add the following line before the Fill method

```
sqla.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```